# How to get record with same fixture in Yii unit test

Tags: yii, phpunit, testcase

Its a parent child relation, 
In childGroup1, getting error during accessing 'PARENT_ID' attribute.
The given error is  **Trying to get property of non-object**.

I am having access dynamically.

How to get **PARENT_ID** in such case.

```
 return array(
    'group1'=>array(
        'ID' => 1,
        'NAME' => 'Test',
        'STATUS' => 1,
    ),

    'childGroup1'=>array(
        'ID' => 2,
        'PARENT_ID' => $this->getRecord('groups','group1')->ID,
        'NAME' => 'Child Test group1',
        'STATUS' => 1,
    ),
 );
```

Comment: Can you tell me, if there is any to set PARENT_ID dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the records are not loaded yet, you cannot use `$this->getRecord()` to acquire a record. As such, just use plain old array logic to get the record's ID.

```
$records = array();
$records['group1'] = array(
    'ID' => 1,
    'NAME' => 'Test',
    'STATUS' => 1,
);

$records['childGroup1'] = array(
    'ID' => 2,
    'PARENT_ID' => $records['group1']['ID'],
    'NAME' => 'Child Test group1',
    'STATUS' => 1,
);
return $records;
```

If you need records from other fixtures, just `require` them.

```
$groups = require __DIR__.'/group.php';
```

This, of course, would be what you put at the top of files OTHER than `groups.php`, in order to gain access to the groups models.